# Git (version 1.7.11-preview20120620) - can't add all subfolders under main project folder

Tags: git, addition

I'm having a difficult time finding an answer to this question, so I'm asking it here.

I have the above-referenced version of Git for Windows installed on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

I have an EXISTING folder that has numerous sub-folders, many of which have spaces in their folder names, and many of the files contained within them have spaces in them. I want the top-level folder to be my "project" folder. I initialized Git in that folder.

When I run "git status" I get the expected "untracked files" message, so I type "git add .".

All the files get added to my project for tracking, but NONE of the sub-folders. After manually adding each and every sub-folder (Ugh!) I hit a wall with one particular sub-folder that will not get added no matter what I try. The folder name has spaces in it, but I've added other sub-folders with spaces successfully. However, I can't get this one to get added. The folder's name is "_04_Spry Script Tests".

I've tried many methods after doing a lot of searches on Google. This is a list of all of the ones I can remember doing. There were probably others, but (my bad) I didn't document every single instance that I tried. Sorry about that.

```
git add .
git add "_04_Spry Script Tests"/.
git add "_04_Spry Script Tests/".
git add */.
git add "_04_Spry*"/.
git add "_04_Spry"*/.
find . -iname "*.*" | xargs git add
git add */\*.*
git add "_04_Spry Script Tests/"\*.*
```

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong or missing?

I thought "git add ." added EVERYTHING under the main project folder. Did I get that wrong?

Thanks in advance for anyone taking the time to give me assistance with this. It's vexing me! =(

Den

---

Response to a question from @BrianCampbell

Hi Brian:

Thanks for responding.

Yes, the sub-folders have files in them.

No, the the `.gitignore` file does not have the folder or any patterns that match the folder's (directory's) name, or any of the files in it.

The folder tree of one of the sub-folders (from the root folder) is:

```
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\_images
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\SCFK_Swim_Lessons_Program.jpg
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\Swim Schedules
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\Swim Schedules\Spring 2010
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\Swim Schedules\Spring 2010\Swim Schedules
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\Swim Schedules\Spring 2010\Swim Schedules\Swim (Schedule) Spring 2010.pdf
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\_images\mock-up.jpg
_04_Spry Script Tests\Programs & Services\SCfK\Swim Academy\_images\SCFK_Swim_Lessons_Program.jpg
```

The root (main project) directory is `_04_Spry Script Tests`

There are many other sub-folders. Does this help?

---

**Edit:** @BrianCampbell, Of course the example I've just given doesn't cause any issues when I test it in the newly initialized Git folder you asked me to copy a sample directory into for illustration! *ugh!* I'm not sure which sub-folder or file would be the issue. There are a lot of them. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything in that folder? Git does not actually track folders themselves; it only tracks files, folders are really only tracked as a component of the filename. If the folder is empty, there's nothing to add. You can add a hidden file to the folder if you want to make sure it gets created on checkout.

Or, do you have a `.gitignore` file in your top level directory, or any subdirectory down to the level of that one? Does it have a pattern that matches that directory name, or the name of all files within it? If so, you should remove such pattern from your `.gitignore`, or use `git add -f` forcibly add it, ignoring your `.gitignore`.

If neither of those suggestions help, can you try and strip down your directory tree to just as much as is necessary to reproduce the problem (just that one directory, or as little as possible to still get the problem), and show the entire directory structure in your question? That would help narrow down what the problem might be. If you have it, `tree` shows a nice listing of the full directory structure; if not, `ls -lR` will do.

**edit**: A few more things to check. For one, I'm a bit confused about your directory structure. Is the `_04_Spry Script Tests` directory the root directory (does it contain the `.git` directory)? Or is that one level up? In many of your examples, you were running `git add _04_Spry Script Tests`, but if that is the root directory, you would need to run `git add` from within it.

One thing to check is if you have nested Git repositories, which can cause problems. Is there a `.git` directory at more than one level? For instance, if there is one outside the `_04_Spry Script Tests` directory, and one within it, and you were trying to add the `_04_Spry Script Tests` directory to the outer repository, you would run into problems.

Another question is what happens when you run `git add`? Do you get any errors, or just no output? Does `git add -v` give you any more information?

If you run `git status`, do you see any information about these directories?

If none of that works, try showing the output of the following commands. If they generate a lot of output, it's OK to trim it down to just the lines including the directories that are having problems:

```
git status -s
git ls-files -cs
git ls-files -io --exclude-standard
git ls-files -d
```

Comment: @WebDevDen It's better to put the updated information in the question; comments are fairly restricted here, to avoid having relevant details scattered through long comment threads. The intent is to get all of the relevant details into the question and answers, and the comments just for clarification and the like. Anyhow, it would be good if you could cut it down to just the relevant directories and files (copy them into a new directory, and do `git init` again if necessary), and show an actual `tree -a` or `ls -alR` so I could see all of the files and directories.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and add it to my original question post. Thanks for the feedback. I'm a noob here. Does the mini-Markdown formatting only work as a predecessor to the word(s) being formatted? I was wrapping them (like HTML markup).

Comment: @WebDevDen The mini-Markdown is fairly restrictive; it only allows very basic markup, like links, code formatted with `\`backquotes\``, *italic*, and **bold**. It doesn't allow any HTML markup, I don't believe. It doesn't allow any kind of newlines or paragraphs. You can make sure someone is notified by writing @TheirName, like I did for you. It's intended for quick comments and clarifications, not long pieces of text (though I will sometimes write longer comments spanning a few different comments). A lot more is allowed in the full Markdown on questions and answers.

Comment: @WebDevDen Oh, and comments are hidden by default after the first 5, to further discourage their use and keep them from taking over the page. You have to click "expand" to see the rest of them. One of the core ideas of StackOverflow is to avoid the problem of forums, in which you need to go through pages of comments before you find the relevant one, by encouraging people to put the important content in questions and answers, with the best answers voted to the top.

Comment: @WebDevDen I've edited my answer to ask you a few more questions and give you a few more things to look at.